# GitHub's password cache helper doesn't recognize git in path

Tags: windows-7, path, github

I'm trying to set up the password caching utility that GitHub recommends for Windows 7 at the bottom of [this page](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git). When I run the installer, it tells me that it can't find GIT in my path environment variable. I've been using git for quite some time, and it most definitely is installed.

I added this to the end of my PATH system variable:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin;
```

and try to run the installer again, but it still isn't recognizing it. It says I can specify the exact path by running

```
git-credential-winstore -i C:\Path\To\Git.exe
```

I don't know how to do this - git-credential-winstore.exe is the name of the downloaded file. I've tried in a command window to run it like this:

```
C:\Users\estrom\Downloads>git-credential-winstore -i C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin
```

and like this:

```
C:\Users\estrom\Downloads>git-credential-winstore -i C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe
```

In both cases, I get the same error messages:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The system cannot find the file specified

   at System.Diagnostics.Process.StartWithShellExecuteEx(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()
   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ProcessStartInfo startInfo)
   at Git.Credential.WinStore.Program.InstallTheApp(String pathToGit, Boolean silent)
   at Git.Credential.WinStore.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

I'm a Linux girl, and really am not familiar with how to do this in Windows. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I contacted GitHub's support, and they provided this:

```
C:\Users\estrom\Downloads>git-credential-winstore -i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\git.exe"
```